# DarkaOnLine / L5-Swagger with Laravel Sanctum Swagger UI

Tags: header, swagger

I found The solution. to add token to header
add follwing code in /config/l5-swagger   in security array

```
    'sanctum' => [ // Unique name of security
        'type' => 'apiKey', // The type of the security scheme. Valid values are "basic", "apiKey" or "oauth2".
        'description' => 'Bearer',
        'name' => 'Authorization', // The name of the header or query parameter to be used.
        'in' => 'header', // The location of the API key. Valid values are "query" or "header".
    ],
```

then in your SWG Annotation put

```
 security={
    {"sanctum": {}},
 },
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. How do you deal with sanctum csrf check? I get a `CSRF token mismatch.` result when click swagger execute btn.

Comment: Just   Bearer  and space and your token
 "Bearer your_token_here"

Comment: I solved csrf error by changing `l5-swagger.php` to let api throgh `web` middleware. And unexpectedly, i can call all request after call login request which return seesion cookie, do not need bearer token anymore. It working pretty good! :)

Comment: How did you do this? I can not find this configuration in `l5-swagger.php`, would you be so kind to share?